# Access cell label outside of cellForRowAtIndexPath i.e button action Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I Have a issue regarding accessing cell label outside of `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. Firstly in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` i am hiding `cell.lblempName.hidden = YES;`

Below is my code :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
     [super viewDidLoad];
     self.tblemplist.tableFooterView=self.footerView;
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    EmployeeCell *cell = (EmployeeCell *) [aTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {

        NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"EmployeeCell" owner:self options:nil];

        for (id currentObject in topLevelObjects){
            if ([currentObject isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]]){
                cell =  (EmployeeCell *) currentObject;

                cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
            }
        }

    }

     NSMutableDictionary *detailsdict=[empArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

     cell.lblTitle.text = [detailsdict objectForKey:@"empTitle"];
     cell.lblItemprice.text = [detailsdict objectForKey:@"empId"];
     cell.lblempName.hidden = YES;
```

}

And in the Footer i have added a View and placed a button. When i click the button `lblempName` should UnHide.

```
- (IBAction)btnApplyClicked:(id)sender {

    // How to unHide cell.lblempName.hidden = NO;

}
```

please help me to find the solution. TIA

Comment: Where do you put `btnApply`? In controller or in `EmployeeCell`?

Comment: button is not in the cell. I have added view to footer and in that view i have place a button. When i click the button the lblempName should display.

Comment: then when it needs to be hide?

Comment: How many cells do you have and if you have more than 1 cell, which cell will be displayed?

Comment: You need add property in view controller for example `empNameHidden`. Use that value in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` implementation. In `btnApplyClicked` set this property to `NO` and call `[tableView reloadData]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create a bool property as `BOOL isEmpNameHidden;`

In **`viewDidLoad`**, set `isEmpNameHidden = YES;`

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    //Your existing code here
    ....

    cell.lblempName.hidden = isEmpNameHidden;
}
```

then unhide based on the button tap

```
- (IBAction)btnApplyClicked:(id)sender {

     isEmpNameHidden = NO;
     [self.tblemplist reloadData]

}
```

Comment: Dispatch to main is not needed.

Comment: @Cy-4AH But when you call [tableView reloadData], you need to call this operation in the main queue know.

Comment: @AntonyRaphel button actions already get called in main queue.

Answer (score 0):

```
EmployeeCell *cell = (EmployeeCell *)[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
UILabel *label = cell.lblempName;
label.hidden = NO;
```

But better is to modify your data, because as soon as the cell scrolls out of the view and back again the label will be visible again since it will be constructed again.